# Is it a good practice to always define `value_type` when we define a template

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class Point
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    ...
};
```

I have seen the above code in the book ["C++ in a Nutshell" by Ray Lischner, pp176](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600298X).

**Questions:**

1. Is it a good practice to always add the definition for `value_type`?
2. Where will this defined `value_type` be used?

For example: `Point<int>::value_type`?

Comment: Is `Point` more like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to have one, but it mostly only makes sense for containers (like `std::vector`), as all containers provide this `typedef` and a uniform interface for accessing the contained values (`begin`/`end`, `front`/`back`), although this has mostly gotten obsolete in C++11 with `auto` and `decltype`. It's still cleaner to say `some_template<typename container::value_type> ...`, though.

That in turn means they can be used interchangeably in generic code (the main reason why things were done that way). If it makes sense for your `Point` class to know what types the contained values are, well, have that `typedef`. As I said, it doesn't hurt. However, I have a feeling that it doesn't make too much sense for that particular example.

Answer (score 10):

It's good practice for writing functions that perform on containers.  For example, if I wrote a `swap` function that accepts a container (templated), and two indices to swap, then I could use the `value_type` definition to define a temp variable.

```
 template<typename T>
 void swap(T &container, int i, int j) {
    typename T::value_type temp = container[i];
    container[i] = container[j];
    container[i] = temp;
 }
```

Comment: And in C++11, that would be `auto`. :) Note that this is kind of a bad example of `swap`, but an adequate one for nested `value_type` typedefs.

Comment: Why can temp not be of type T here ?

Comment: T is the container type, not the type of the value stored in the container.

Comment: @Xeo Better hope that's a *true* container then, instead of something like `std::vector<bool>`. Anyway, yes, it should use `using std::swap; swap(container[i], container[j]);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say only if it makes sense for the type. I've run into troubles where value_type gets in the way because some generic algorithm wrongfully assumes it's a container of some sort ( in my case, I seem to recall it was some algorithm in boost that assumed shared_ptr was a container multi item container due to value_type being present ).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it definitely does make sense to provide `value_type` definition to the coordinate type of the point. With this practice, you define your own *concept* how a point type has to be defined which is super useful because you can develop templated algorithms like these:

```
template <class TPoint>
struct Algorithms
{
   TPoint::value_type SmallestCoordinate(const std::vector<TPoint>& points);

   std::vector<TPoint> SelectPoints(const std::vector<TPoint>& points,
                                    std::vector<typename TPoint::value_type> thresholds);
}
```

These algorithms can be independent from the point class implementation if you define a well described concept what a point should provide. For example:

- `operator[](size_t i)` provides the `i`th coordinate of the point
- `size()` returns the number of dimensions (coordinates).
- **`value_type` provides the coordinate type.**

This means that you can have you own `MyPoint` implementation:

```
template<typename T>
class Point
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    value_type x{};
    value_type y{};

    size_t size()
    {
        return 2u;
    }

    value_type operator[](size_t i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: return x;
            case 1: return y;
            default: throw std::out_of_range();
        }
    }
};
```

Or you can also use this:

```
template <typename T>
using Point = std::array<T, 2>;
```

The defined algorithms above work similarly well.