# Streamlined Way of Making Template Parameters Public?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, public

I keep facing the situation that I have a class that takes some template parameters, that I want to be publicly available via `CLASS::TYPE`. For that I always do public typedefs, like this:

```
template <class Tx>
Class C
{
public:
typedef Tx Ty;

};
```

This is awkward for 2 reasons:

- it feels clunky and redundant
- to avoid shadowing I need to give two different names (`Tx` and `Ty`) to the same thing, which really bugs me.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's a common convention in the standard library to `typedef` this sort of thing as one of a small set of names, e.g., [`element_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [`value_type`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637094/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-define-value-type-when-we-define-a-template), or `type`, based on the context. Can't say that I see much of a problem with doing that.

Comment: @AmiTavory sorry, I am a little lost as to how this is an answer to my question. Can you help me out a little more?

Comment: It's actually not an answer, just a comment. 1. If you'd use the library conventions, template parameters would be UpperCase and types lowercase, so no shadowing would be take place, and, moreover, it would be relatively easy to guess what the name of the type is. 2. Since the standard library does it, it's some indication that there's no easy alternative. ---- Again, I don't think this is a full-fledged answer, so that's why I wrote it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `decltype` syntax, deduction and tag dispatching:

```
template <class Tx>
struct C { };

template <class T>
struct tag { };

template <class T>
T deduceCTx(tag<C<T>>);

// now to extract type:
decltype(deduceCTx(tag<C<int>>{})) a; // a is of type int
```

In more general case (and when using at least c++11) you could create deduce function to extract any template type parameter using template template syntax and variadic templates:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class Tx>
struct C { };

template <class T>
struct tag { };

template <size_t N, template <class...> class TT, class... Args>
typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type 
    deduceAnyTypeTemplateParameter(tag<TT<Args...>>);

// now to extract type:
decltype(deduceAnyTypeTemplateParameter<0>(tag<C<int>>{})) a; // a is of type int
```

If you are using c++14 you could make usage of your deduction more convenient by utilizing type alias:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class Tx>
struct C { };

template <class T>
struct tag { };

template <size_t N, template <class...> class TT, class... Args>
typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type
    deduceAnyTemplateParameter(tag<TT<Args...>>);

// now to use passed type:
 decltype(deduceAnyTemplateParameter<0>(tag<C<int>>{})) a; // a is of type int

template <size_t N, class T>
using TemplateParameter = decltype(deduceAnyTemplateParameter<N>(tag<T>{}));

int main() {
  TemplateParameter<0, C<int>> i; // i of type int
}
```

Comment: Neat trick, but I think OP was looking for something *less* awkward and clunky.