# get type of element in range based loop **directly** e.g. for "using"

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, foreach, iterator

How to get type of **return value** ***of*** ranged-base loop elegantly?

I currently use this :-  (it works OK)

```
using Encapsulator= std::vector<int>;  //<-- any datastructure
using ReturnType = decltype(std::declval<Encapsulator>().begin().operator*());
//^ ReturnType is "int&"
```

**Objective:** `ReturnType` is a type that fit the word `auto` in:-

```
for(auto returnType : an-instance-of-Encapsulator ){}
```

However, I think my above code is not elegant at all.
I feel dizzy after staring it for a long time.

### **Question**

Is there anything in **standard library / syntax** that works elegantly like this?

```
using ReturnType = std::rangedBasedLoopType<Encapsulator>;
```

I wonder that I should code `rangedBasedLoopType` myself, but I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

### My reinventing the wheel

My bad ... I can't resist.  This code works OK.

```
template<class Collection> using GetReturn =
    decltype(std::declval<Collection>().begin().operator*());
using ReturnType = GetReturn<Encapsulator>;
```

**Edit (after accept answer):**

For me, both answers are very good.  Thank a lot!
**R Sahu**'s is neat, while **Cheers and hth. - Alf**'s is more robust.
It is a pity that I can accept only one, so I select the one that suitable for my *small* project.

Comment: Most standard library "data structures" have a `value_type` member type. Is that what you are looking for? Also, the value returned by `begin()` can be a raw pointer, which will then not have an `operator*()` member.

Comment: @Bo Persson   You comment is very useful!  I never know that it can be a raw pointer, thank! I just know after you said why it was named `*`, ha ha.   By the way, the data structures are created by me, so there is no such field (in some case, `begin()` return different type other than `T` too).  Is it a good practice to create/define `value_type` for all of my data-structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct method:

```
using Encapsulator= std::vector<int>;
using ItemType = Encapsulator::value_type;   //
using ValueType = Encapsulator::value_type;  // Use on of these three
using ReturnType = Encapsulator::value_type; //
```

All standard library containers support `value_type`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container.

Comment: Never heard about it before, thank.   My data-structure don't have `value_type`.  Should I add `value_type` to all of them? ... More specifically, do all *good-quality* data structures have to define `value_type`, in your opinion?

Comment: @javaLover, all classes that implement the notion of a "Container" of other objects should do that.

Comment: For reference to future readers and myself, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637094/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-define-value-type-when-we-define-a-template) is a link to support R Sahu's answer - `value_type` + custom data-structure.

Answer (score 1):

In a little hobby project I currently use the following code (it also works for raw arrays, and for containers without a `value_type` typedef):

```
template< class T >
struct Collection_traits_
    : Non_instantiable
{
    using Collection =
        remove_reference_t<T>;

    using Iterator =
        decltype( begin( declval< ref_<Collection> >() ) );

    using Const_iterator =
        decltype( begin( declval< ref_<const Collection> >() ) );

    using Item =
        remove_reference_t< decltype( *declval< Iterator >() ) >;

    using Const_item = 
        remove_reference_t< decltype( *declval< Const_iterator >() ) >;
};
```

where

```
template< class Some_type >
using ref_ = Some_type&;
```

and `remove_reference_t`, `begin` and `declval` are from the standard library.

Comment: Thank!   .... If my data-structure has `begin()` as a non-static member function, I need to modify your code, right?  ... Will `begin(collection)` call my `collection.begin()` indirectly?  ... I may have to use SFINAE to support both cases?

Comment: [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) defaults to calling a member function `begin`.